# FFMPEG with the drupal video module

Tags: files

I'm trying to use FFMPEG with the drupal video module, I'm using a Centos 6.4 VPS. I followed the Official compile guide "https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide" and I have no errors. but after all the video module is not finding the FFMPEG I tried couple pathes but didn't find it
I tried these

**$which ffmpeg:** 
/root/bin/ffmpeg

**whereis ffmpeg** return nothing

**ffmpeg -version**
ffmpeg version git-2013-11-29-6e7de11
built on Nov 29 2013 14:42:14 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libtheora
libavutil      52. 55.100 / 52. 55.100
libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
libavformat    55. 21.102 / 55. 21.102
libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100

Any suggestions?

Comment: /root/bin/ffmpeg is not the correct path it should be in usr folder.Recheck the installed folder.

Comment: is that should be changed in the installation process?https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide if so, which step??

Comment: According to my knowledge, it shuld be usr folder, check one time with that folder, did you put install path to transcoder page of video configuration

Comment: I did, looks like something wrong with that guide, it's not installing compiling it correctly. I don't see any errors during the installation though.

Comment: follow this installation https://d.stavrovski.net/blog/yum-install-ffmpeg-and-ffmpeg-php-in-centos-6-with-virtualmin/

Comment: Thanks Madhurjya, I want to compile the WEBM and OGG , and this guide will not let me do that